# CMake Error : Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR system thread regex iostreams)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Windows 10
Cmake version : 3.24.0
Boost version : 1.66.0
CLion version : 2022.1.3

Do you have any idea about how i can fix this ?
I found on other topics some answer but it didn't work for me.

```
C:\Users\33671\AppData\Local\JetBrains\CLion2022.1\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/cygdrive/c/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2022.1.3/bin/ninja/cygwin/ninja.exe" -G Ninja -S /cygdrive/c/Users/33671/Desktop/main_program-master -B /cygdrive/c/Users/33671/Desktop/main_program-master/cmake-build-debug-cygwin
  -- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
  -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++.exe - skipped
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Looking for pthread.h
  -- Looking for pthread.h - found
  -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
  -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
  -- Found Threads: TRUE  
  CMake Error at /cygdrive/c/Users/33671/AppData/Local/JetBrains/CLion2022.1/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.22.3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
    Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR system thread regex
    iostreams)
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /cygdrive/c/Users/33671/AppData/Local/JetBrains/CLion2022.1/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.22.3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
    /cygdrive/c/Users/33671/AppData/Local/JetBrains/CLion2022.1/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.22.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2375 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
    CMakeLists.txt:10 (FIND_PACKAGE)


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/33671/Desktop/main_program-master/cmake-build-debug-cygwin/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

  [Finished]
```

Also my CMakeList.txt is like this :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS NO)
SET(Boost_USE_MULTITHREAD ON)
SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /lib/)


FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread regex iostreams)#  1.66.0

IF(Boost_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
ENDIF(Boost_FOUND)
SET(USED_LIBS ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY} ${Boost_THREAD_LIBRARY} ${Boost_REGEX_LIBRARY} ${Boost_IOSTREAMS_LIBRARY})
```

Comment: Did you install boost, and if so where?

Comment: See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html for how find boost works

Comment: @Botje yes in my C:/

Comment: @programZozo I think passing `-DBOOST_ROOT=C:\<your_boost_folder_name>` to CMake should do.

Comment: @rturrado I did in the command prompt : "cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=C:\boost_1_66_0" but it gave a warning and an error : CMake Warning: 
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Users/33671" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

Comment: @programZozo you'll still need to run your previous CMake command; just add the BOOST_ROOT option to that command; you have to run it from the directory where you have the top CMakeLists.txt or point to it, e.g. `cmake ..` or something like that; lastly, take care with backslashes to express the boost root dir: try escaping them or simply use forward slashes.